# Opening Serial Port with PureJavaComm leads to PortInUseException

Tags: java, exception, jboss, serial-port, windows-7-x64

for reading a GPS signal from COM3, I'm trying to connect to the port via Java using PureJavaComm (http://www.sparetimelabs.com/purejavacomm/purejavacomm.php)

Using the code below all of the systems COM ports are found and listed:

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    Enumeration portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
    while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
        CommPortIdentifier portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
        if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
            list.add(portId.getName());
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Ports: " + list.toString());
```

Nevertheless, if I'm trying to connect to one port by using the below code I'm getting a PortInUseException. The weird thing is, the exception appears by using the code on all com ports, even the ones which are simulated.

```
    try {
        portId = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("COM3");
    } catch (NoSuchPortException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    SerialPort serialPort = null;
    try {
         serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("GpsApp", 2000);
         serialPort.close();
    } catch (PortInUseException e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
```

`portId.currentOwner()` returns `null` and `portId.isCurrentlyOwned` returns `false`. On the other side, connecting to the same port by using putty works just fine.

Do you have any ideas? I'm using a Win7 x64 OS and 64Bit Java 1.7, the deployment server is a JBoss 7.2.0

I already tried to disable the COM Port I want to connect to, restart and enable it again. Unfortunately, it didn't help.

Comment: Put the `serialPort.close()` in a finally block. Also, you seem to be missing `Termios`. What permissions are `2000`? The example on your link is `int fd = open(port, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);`, use the symbolic names!

Comment: Hi Elliott, thanks for answering. The example in the link is in case anybody wants to use the jtermios.JTermios. However, if you don't, PureJavaComm works just exactly like JavaComm (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/javacomm/reference/api/index.html)

2000 is not the permission, it's the max timeout in ms.

Comment: I don't think that is the case. Let's test your assertion. Change from PureJavaComm to Oracle JavaComm and your code works? Then I don't think they are exactly the same.

Comment: I already tried the Oracle JavaComm but would like to be independent off the win32com.dll it needs. What I meant is that PureJavaComm provides exactly the same classes and methods as the Oracle/Sun JavaComm or RXTX.

Comment: This old so I won't try to diagnose this, but as the author of the PureJavaComm I suggest asking for help in the github at https://github.com/nyholku/purejavacomm is more likely to provide useful help…